# EJB MDB listening through JCA adapter failing on starting

Tags: java, ejb, jca

I am writing this MDB which will listen message on IBM MQ queues and onMessage it will make call to ilrsession for running jrules. JCA adapter 
 and Activation config is configured on WAS console

While starting this MDB throws the following error.  Is it the static block which is why its failing.

I am posting here if something can review the code and provide some suggestions.

Here is the exception I get while starting the MDB.

```
An operation in the enterprise bean constructor failed. It is recommended that component initialization logic be placed in a PostConstruct method instead of the bean class no-arg constructor.; nested exception is:
            java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startBean(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:620)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.startBean(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:586)
            at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.fireMetaDataCreatedAndStartBean(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:1715)
            at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:667)
            ... 52 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is the MDB Code.

```
package com.abc.integration.ejb

import ilog.rules.res.model.IlrPath;
import ilog.rules.res.session.IlrEJB3SessionFactory;
import ilog.rules.res.session.IlrSessionException;
import ilog.rules.res.session.IlrSessionRequest;
import ilog.rules.res.session.IlrSessionResponse;
import ilog.rules.res.session.IlrStatelessSession;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;


/**
 * Message-Driven Bean implementation class for: DecisionServiceMDB
 * 
 */


@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue") })
public class DecisionServiceMDB implements MessageListener
{
    /**
     * default serial version id
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2300836924029589692L;
    private static final Logger responseTimeLogger = Logger.getLogger(PropertyManager.getResponseTimeLogger());
    private static final Logger errorLogger = Logger.getLogger(PropertyManager.getErrorLogger());
    private static final Logger ruleExceptionLogger = Logger.getLogger(PropertyManager.getRuleExceptionLogger());


    private static final String RULEAPP_NAME = PropertyManager.getRuleAppName();
    private static final String RULESET_NAME = PropertyManager.getRuleSetName();

    private static InitialContext ic;
    private static ConnectionFactory cf;
    private static Destination destination;
    private static String qcfLookup = PropertyManager.getQueueFactoryJndiName();
    private static String qLookup = PropertyManager.getQueueDestinationJndiName();

    private Connection c = null;
    private Session s = null;
    private MessageProducer mp = null;

    private boolean isInitializedOkay = true;

    private static IlrEJB3SessionFactory factory;
    private static IlrStatelessSession ruleSession;
    private static IlrPath path;
    private IlrSessionRequest sessionRequest;

    static {
        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("log4j.xml");
        DOMConfigurator.configure(url);
        errorLogger.info("log4j xml initialized::::::::::::::::");
    }

    public DecisionServiceMDB() throws NamingException, JMSException
    {
        try
        {

            if (ic == null)
            {
                ic = new InitialContext();
            }
            if (cf == null)
            {
                cf = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(qcfLookup);
            }
            if (destination == null)
            {
                destination = (Destination) ic.lookup(qLookup);
            }

        } catch (NamingException e)
        {
            isInitializedOkay = false;
            errorLogger.error("FATAL:NamingException Occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            errorLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            //throw e;
        }

        // 1. Get a POJO Session Factory
         if (factory == null)
        {
             //factory = new IlrJ2SESessionFactory();
            //to log rule execution start time by using bre logger
            //transactionLogger.setRuleExecutionStartTime(new Date());
            factory = new IlrEJB3SessionFactory();

            // As the EJBS are embedded within the ear file, we need to prepend
            // the ear file name to the JNDI.
            factory.setStatelessLocalJndiName("ejblocal:ilog.rules.res.session.ejb3.IlrStatelessSessionLocal");
        }

        // 2. Create a stateless rule session using this factory
        try
        {
            if (ruleSession == null)
            {
                ruleSession = factory.createStatelessSession();
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return;
        }

        // 3. Create a session request to invoke the RES (defining the ruleset
        // path and the input ruleset parameters)
        if (path == null)
        {
            path = new IlrPath(RULEAPP_NAME, RULESET_NAME);
        }

        sessionRequest = factory.createRequest();
        sessionRequest.setRulesetPath(path);
    }

   public void onMessage(Message receivedMsg)
   { 
  // onMessage code goes here. 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are violating programming restrictions (see EJB spec 16.2.2):

> An enterprise bean must not use read/write static fields. Using read-only static fields is allowed. Therefore, it is recommended that all static fields in the enterprise bean class be declared as final.

Remove your (non-final) static fields, your static initializer and the constructor. Intialisation is done within the postConstruct lifecycle callback method.

Your EJB could look like this:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue") })
public class DecisionServiceMDB implements MessageListener
{

    private Logger responseTimeLogger;
    private Logger errorLogger;
    private Logger ruleExceptionLogger;

    private String RULEAPP_NAME;
    private String RULESET_NAME;

    private InitialContext ic;
    private ConnectionFactory cf;
    private Destination destination;
    private String qcfLookup;
    private String qLookup;

    private Connection c;
    private Session s;
    private MessageProducer mp;

    private boolean isInitializedOkay = true;

    private IlrEJB3SessionFactory factory;
    private IlrStatelessSession ruleSession;
    private IlrPath path;
    private IlrSessionRequest sessionRequest;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        responseTimeLogger = Logger.getLogger(PropertyManager.getResponseTimeLogger());
        errorLogger = Logger.getLogger(PropertyManager.getErrorLogger());
        ruleExceptionLogger = Logger.getLogger(PropertyManager.getRuleExceptionLogger());

        RULEAPP_NAME = PropertyManager.getRuleAppName();
        RULESET_NAME = PropertyManager.getRuleSetName();

        qcfLookup = PropertyManager.getQueueFactoryJndiName();
        qLookup = PropertyManager.getQueueDestinationJndiName();

        ic = new InitialContext();
        cf = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(qcfLookup);
        destination = (Destination) ic.lookup(qLookup);

        factory = new IlrEJB3SessionFactory();
        factory.setStatelessLocalJndiName("ejblocal:ilog.rules.res.session.ejb3.IlrStatelessSessionLocal");

        ruleSession = factory.createStatelessSession();
        sessionRequest.setRulesetPath(path);
    }

    public void onMessage(Message receivedMsg)
    {
        // onMessage code goes here. 
    }

}
```

I removed the static initializer. Looks like you try to configure logging, which should not be done within your EJB. Refer to the documentation of your application server how to do this properly.

This is just some example code based on the original code.

The implementation you provided looks like a plain java implementation. Be aware of requirements in an enterprise environment (e.g. EJB lifecycle, EJB providers responsibility, ...). Read the EJB spec and some JEE tutorials before proceeding.

With this in mind, you should take a look at your PropertyManager afterwards. This might not be implemented in a suitable manner.

Comment: I added some example code and indications to the answer.